# Why are classmethods blind to normal methods when instantiated?

Tags: python, class, methods, instantiation, class-method

## Questions

1. Why are classmethods blind to normal methods when instantiated?
2. Is there a way to pass `self` to allow classmethods *see* normal methods when instantiated?

## Observations

### Uninstantiated classmethods

- When using a class method, the modification of any attribute will persist.
- I expected each use of a class function to only temporarily store the attributes whilst the classmethod ran

### Instantiated classmethods

- Classmethods cannot use any variable that is set from a normal method
- Even if the class is instantiated, the classmethods are still totally blind to anything that is done in normal methods!
- This is unexpected behavior. I would expect classmethods to behave as normal methods once instantiated!

## Example Code

```
def fmt_atts(self, att):
    """A simple formatter"""
    if hasattr(self, att): print '\t self.{:15s} = {}'.format(att, getattr(self, att))
    else: print "\t self.{:15s} does not exist".format(att)

def _report_vals(func):
    """This just reports the current state of values"""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        print '> calling func: {} :: {}'.format(func.__name__, func.__doc__)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        for att in self.all_attrs:
            fmt_atts(self, att)
        print '> end func: {}'.format(func.__name__)
        return res
    return wrapper

class Example(object):
    all_attrs = ['att_class', 'att_clsFnSet', 'att_initSet']
    att_class = 'set_in_class'

    @_report_vals
    def __init__(self):
        """setting an attribute and calling self.test2"""
        self.att_initSet = 'set_in_init'
        self.set_atts_in_classmethod()

    @classmethod
    @_report_vals
    def set_atts_in_classmethod(cls):
        """Sets attributes from within a classmethod"""
        cls.att_class = 'set_in_classmethod'
        cls.att_clsFnSet = 'set_in_classmethod'

    @classmethod
    @_report_vals
    def view_atts_from_classmethod(cls):
        """View attributes from a classmethod"""
        pass

    @_report_vals
    def view_atts_from_method(self):
        """View attributes from a normal method"""
        pass

    @_report_vals
    def set_atts_in_method(self):
        """Sets attributes from within a normal method"""
        self.att_class = 'set_in_method'
        self.att_clsFnSet = 'set_in_method'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print '__without init'
    print '> calling `Example.att_class` directly'
    fmt_atts(Example, 'att_class')
    print '# comment: notice that `A.att_class` has a persisting value'
    Example.set_atts_in_classmethod()
    Example.view_atts_from_classmethod()

    print '\n__ post init: ex = Example()'
    ex = Example()
    print '# comment: notice that `self.att_initSet` has been set but not accessible from classmethod'
    ex.set_atts_in_classmethod()
    ex.view_atts_from_classmethod()
    print '# comment: notice that `self.att_initSet` was set in __init__ but not avialable!'
    print '# comment: however, `self.att_class` was set in another classmethod but *IS* accessible'
    ex.view_atts_from_method()
    print '# comment: notice that `self.att_initSet` is accessible from a normal method'
    ex.set_atts_in_method()
    ex.view_atts_from_classmethod()
    print '# comment: It appears that classmethods can only access attributes set by other classmethods'
    print '# comment: even when instanciated'
```

## Output Example

```
__without init
> calling `Example.att_class` directly
        self.att_class       = set_in_class
# comment: notice that `A.att_class` has a persisting value
> calling func: set_atts_in_classmethod :: Sets attributes from within a classmethod
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     does not exist
> end func: set_atts_in_classmethod
> calling func: view_atts_from_classmethod :: View attributes from a classmethod
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     does not exist
> end func: view_atts_from_classmethod

__ post init: ex = Example()
> calling func: __init__ :: setting an attribute and calling self.test2
> calling func: set_atts_in_classmethod :: Sets attributes from within a classmethod
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     does not exist
> end func: set_atts_in_classmethod
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     = set_in_init
> end func: __init__
# comment: notice that `self.att_initSet` has been set but not accessible from classmethod
> calling func: set_atts_in_classmethod :: Sets attributes from within a classmethod
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     does not exist
> end func: set_atts_in_classmethod
> calling func: view_atts_from_classmethod :: View attributes from a classmethod
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     does not exist
> end func: view_atts_from_classmethod
# comment: notice that `self.att_initSet` was set in __init__ but not avialable!
# comment: however, `self.att_class` was set in another classmethod but *IS* accessible
> calling func: view_atts_from_method :: View attributes from a normal method
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     = set_in_init
> end func: view_atts_from_method
# comment: notice that `self.att_initSet` is accessible from a normal method
> calling func: set_atts_in_method :: Sets attributes from within a normal method
        self.att_class       = set_in_method
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_method
        self.att_initSet     = set_in_init
> end func: set_atts_in_method
> calling func: view_atts_from_classmethod :: View attributes from a classmethod
        self.att_class       = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_clsFnSet    = set_in_classmethod
        self.att_initSet     does not exist
> end func: view_atts_from_classmethod
# comment: It appears that classmethods can only access attributes set by other classmethods
# comment: even when instantiated
```

Comment: Posting from my phone - tidying up code syntax !

Comment: You appear to have some misunderstanding about what classmethods do, and class attributes vs instance attributes. But it's not easy to read your code in its current state.

Comment: Yes terribly sorry my workplace blocks stack overflow. I'm having to email my question to my phone and edit here. I think I've got a workaround for this formatting issue

Comment: Syntax fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why are classmethods blind to normal methods when instantiated?

Class (or static) methods are not meant to act on instances. They are methods that are common to *all the instances* of the class. Therefore, it is not logical for a class method to act on one specific instance.

These are generally utilitary functions. For example, a `Vector` class could implement a `dot_product` as a class method, rather than an instance method. This would make sense, because such an operation involves more than one instance.

### Is there a way to pass self to allow classmethods see normal methods when instantiated?

Yes, there is, though it does not really make sense.

First off, a class method **is able** to see instance methods. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def speak(self):
        print("Hello")

    @classmethod
    def make_speak(cls, instance):
        instance.speak()

foo = Foo()
Foo.make_speak(foo)
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Let's go further, and change a little the `make_speak` method:

```
@classmethod
def make_speak(cls):
    print(cls.speak)

Foo.make_speak()
```

Output:

```
<function Foo.speak at 0x000001E58331EF28>
```

What this output reveals, is that the `speak` method referred to by `cls.speak` actually corresponds to a `speak` method that has not been attached to any instance. This can be seen even clearer when calling that function:

```
@classmethod
def make_speak(cls):
    cls.speak()

Foo.make_speak()
```

Output:

```
TypeError: speak() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

An `TypeError` is raised, because the `speak` method from the `Foo` class needs one argument, which is not passed.

#### Workaround

*Disclaimer: The following is **not** a good solution.*

The `speak` method needs an instance as argument to be run. Then, just give it:

```
@classmethod
def make_speak(cls, instance):
    cls.speak(instance)

foo = Foo()
Foo.make_speak(foo)
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

But by doing this, you want the `make_speak` method to act on a specific `Foo` instance, so as to call its `speak` method.

This is exactly tantamount to directly calling `foo.speak`.

---

This example might seem obvious and dull. However, it highlights the fact that if a class method takes exactly one instance as argument (and potentially other things that are not instances of this class), then it is **equivalent to an instance method**.

Comment: I hope my edited format makes it clearer. Apologies for the previous mess! The classmethod seems to not properly "see" the instance method because it cannot interact with instance attributes set / modified or set during the operation. Is there any workaround for this? Or am I misunderstanding their purpose?

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane I finished my answer. Does it make it clearer?

Comment: I'll have a look through it this afternoon - thanks for the extra detail